# Custom Connection to database

Tags: database

I am trying to create a custom connection to my database through `Magento 2.1.8`.

I am trying to use the `mysqli` library.

The method I am using worked in Magento 1.9 but will not work in my current version.

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);
```

When i use this code, i am receiving an error:

> Uncaught Error: Class 'VendorName\Forum\Controller\Post\mysqli' not
>   found in
>   /domains/mywebsite.com/http/app/code/VendorName/Forum/Controller/Post/postMessage.php:28

How do i import the mysqli class to create this object?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write a below code with backslash

> $conn = new \mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);

Comment: excellent, this worked for me Thank you. Why does adding the backslash make this work?